# Can I create empty Tuple or String in Scala?

Tags: scala

I need return tuple , but if something goes wrong I want return empty tuple, like `Seq.empty[Type]` or `Nil` in Lists. Is it possible?
Also I am curious about is it possible with String type.

Comment: You need to return a tuple, but presumably, you can't just return any tuple. So what kind of tuple do you want to return? If the size changes, wouldn't `List` be more appropriate?

Comment: If you would like to consider an alternative approach http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/12/19/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-5-the-option-type.html

Comment: If you want to return 1 or 0 items, use `Option[T]`.

Comment: While Option[T] is certainly the standard solution to that problem, depending on your specific usecase another approach may be possible. If the types in your tuple each form a monoid, it may make sense to return a tuple containing the Zero elements of each type.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I want return empty tuple

That doesn't make sense. A tuple is not a collection. The idea of "emptiness" is simply non-sensical. The length of a tuple is part of its type. So, an empty tuple is a different type than a non-empty tuple.

In fact, it doesn't even make sense to talk about "tuple" as a type. There are pairs (2-tuples aka `Tuple2`), triples (3-tuples aka `Tuple3`), quadruples, quintuples, sixtuples, septuples, octuples, 9-tuples, 10-tuples, etc, and they are all *different* types.

Also, more or less the only sensible thing you can do with a tuple is to extract its elements. So, for a tuple with no elements, there is pretty much no sensible thing you can do. What use is a structure that holds no values and has no operations? It's completely useless.

In fact, a 0-tuple is isomorphic to the `Unit` value, the value which denotes the absence of a useful value. In Scala, and also Haskell, the syntax for an empty tuple is actually used for denoting the `Unit` value:

```
val u = ()
// => u: Unit = ()
```

> Also I am curious about is it possible with String type.

Yes, of course, you can have an empty string:

```
val s = ""
// => s: String = ""
```

Comment: "Also, more or less the only sensible thing you can do with a tuple is to extract its elements" To be precise, there are two things you can do with a tuple, construct it and extract its elements.

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to return an a value that can go wrong. In Scala the recommended way to deal with this is returning an Option, Try or Either value.

For instance:

```
def somethingThatCanGoWrongWithTry(): Try[(Int, String)] = {
  Try{
    val intValue = sideEffectValueInt()
    val stringValue = sideEffectValueString()
    (intValue, stringValue)
  }
}

def somethingThatCanGoWrongWithOption(): Option[(Int,String)] = {
  Try {
    val intValue = sideEffectValueInt()
    val stringValue = sideEffectValueString()
    (intValue, stringValue)
  }.toOption
}

def somethingThatCanGoWrongWithEither(): Either[Oops, (Int,String)] = {
  Try {
    val intValue = sideEffectValueInt()
    val stringValue = sideEffectValueString()
    (intValue, stringValue)
  } match {
    case Success(value) => Right(value)
    case Failure(exception) => Left(Oops(exception))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Can I create empty Tuple in Scala?

In Scala 3, empty tuple is represented by case object [`EmptyTuple`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/3.x/scala/EmptyTuple$.html). Also empty tuple is returned by [`Tuple()` (i.e. `Tuple.apply()`, without parameters)](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/3.x/scala/Tuple$.html#apply-bd).

```
val v = Tuple()
println(v == EmptyTuple) // true
println(v.isInstanceOf[Tuple]) // true
println(v.productArity) // 0
```

Also (offtopic) you can create a tuple of size 1 by any of the following ways:

- `Tuple(myValue)`, `Tuple.apply(myValue)`, `Tuple.apply[MyValueType](myValue)`,
- `Tuple1(myValue)`, `Tuple1[MyValueType](myValue)`,
- `myValue *: EmptyTuple`, `myValue *: Tuple()`.

The type of result is [`Tuple1[MyValueType]`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/3.x/scala/Tuple1.html) a.k.a. [`MyValueType *: EmptyTuple`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/3.x/scala/*:.html) (it's a subtype of [`NonEmptyTuple`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/3.x/scala/NonEmptyTuple.html), which is, of course, a subtype of [`Tuple`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/3.x/scala/Tuple.html)).

#### Can I create empty String in Scala?

[Sure](/a/37417338).